# Restore filegroup without log sequence number (LSN)

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have the following error:

> The roll forward start point is now at log sequence number (LSN) 5470633000000066000001. Additional roll forward past LSN 19429240000000043500001 is required to complete the restore sequence.

Now I explain: I have a database in "restoring..." mode, because I applied a restore of files and filegroups, from a .bak file that I took in the past, but I do not have a transaction log file of the type .trn with the LSN 19429240000000043500001, to recover the database. What can I do to bring the database back online or return the restore process without losing the other ndf child data that was in the database?

Image restoration process failed:
[image: Image restoration process failed]

Comment: Please clarify, what are the filegroups?  Which ones are read/write and which are read-only?  Which ones are present in your backups?  Why are you doing a restore?  Where are your full backups?  Why don't you have log backups?

Comment: If you don't have the relevant log backup files, you could potentially restore using `STOPATMARK = 'lsn:5470633....` to stop at a point which you *do* have. Obviously you then lose all changes past that point

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server will *not* give you a database where different parts of the data are from different points in time. If you restore a part of the database from an earlier point in time, then there are two scenarios:

1. The filegroups affected by that restore **has been read only** since that backup was taken. SQL Server knows that no modifications could have been performed on the data that was restore and no subsequent log backups are required.
2. The filegroups affected by that restore **has not been read only** since that backup was taken. SQL Server need an unbroken chain of log backups so it can re-do all the modifications on the restored data so it is up-to-date with the rest of the database. If you are missing any of those required log backups, then the filegroups affected by that restore will be "defunct" and will forever be a "dead" and inaccessible part of that database.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your database restoration is encountering an issue due to the absence of required log backups. To troubleshoot, first, ensure that the affected filegroups have been set to read-only since the backup was taken. Confirm the existence of a complete chain of log backups, as their absence may impede the restoration process. Additionally, consider using the STOPATMARK option, stopping the restore at a specific Log Sequence Number (LSN) where a relevant log backup is available; however, be cautious of potential data loss beyond that point. Investigate logs for any indications of corruption during the restore process. Reviewing your database documentation and providing specific error details will aid in a more precise diagnosis.